# android GCM Receive Messages from Multiple devices

Tags: broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

i am building a chat application with the help of GoogleCloudMessaging(GCM).i am able to send and receive messages. my problem is when i receive messages from multiple devices at the same time, all those messages are appended to the same list-view in my broadcast receiver class. how can i separate the message based on the senders and append the current chat message to the listview. and make separate notifications for other messages based on the senders and when i click on the notification it should open the same list view with messages according to sender.

can any one give me an efficient way of doing this.if you have any sample code to handle this situation please post the code.

**My current code:**

```
 public class Serious extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String action=intent.getAction();
         if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"))
         {
             String registrationID=intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
            // Log.i("uo",registrationID);
             String error=intent.getStringExtra("error");
             String unregisterd=intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");

         }
         else if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"))
         {
             String data1=intent.getStringExtra("data1");
             String data2=intent.getStringExtra("data2");
             addNewMessage(new Message(data2, false));

            /* PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My Notification")
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText(data1+data2);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


                NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());*/



         }

    }
     void addNewMessage(Message m)
        {
            MainActivity.messages.add(m);
            MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //MainActivity.getListView().setSelection(MainActivity.messages.size()-1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass in your gcm message a parameter that contains the sender id. Then, when you handle the arrived message,  use that sender id to decide where to add that message.  In order to show multiple notifications, pass different int values to notify.  Currently you always pass 1, so a new notification overrides the old one.

Comment: i need to store the messages on mobile database to maintain the stack or is there will be any api in gcm to retrieve the messages by passing the registrationid

Comment: and also if i get different messages from different registrationid's can i show a notification on a particular registrationid from list of registrationid's  if so could u please give sample code.                if there is any complete chat application with multiple users post that project or link to me so that i can get an idea of handling data from multiple registrationid's(friends) at a time.    please provide some help on this topic

Comment: @madanV You have to either store the messages on mobile database or load them from your server when the app is launched. There is no API in GCM to retrieve old messages (they are not store in GCM server after delivery).

Comment: Thanks for your reply do you have any working sample of the project. how can I sync my mobile contacts with the server database similar to whatsapp.